# Remove numbers from filenames

Tags: find, xargs, mv, parallelism

I've a problem modifying the files' names in my `Music/`  directory.

I have a list of names like these:

```
$ ls
01 American Idiot.mp3
01 Articolo 31 - Domani Smetto.mp3
01 Bohemian rapsody.mp3
01 Eye of the Tiger.mp3
04 Halo.mp3
04 Indietro.mp3
04 You Can't Hurry Love.mp3
05 Beautiful girls.mp3
16 Apologize.mp3
16 Christmas Is All Around.mp3
Adam's song.mp3
A far l'amore comincia tu.mp3
All By My Self.MP3
Always.mp3
Angel.mp3
```

And similar and I would like to cut all the numbers in front of the filenames (not the 3 in the extension).

I've tried first to `grep` only the files with the number with `find -exec` or `xargs` but even at this first step I had no success. After being able to `grep` I'd like doing the actual name change.

This is what I tried by now:

```
ls > try-expression
grep -E '^[0-9]+' try-expression
```

and with the above I got the right result. Then I tried the next step:

```
ls | xargs -0 grep -E '^[0-9]+'
ls | xargs -d '\n' grep -E '^[0-9]+'
find . -name '[0-9]+' -exec grep -E '^[0-9]+' {} \;
ls | parallel bash -c "grep -E '^[0-9]+'" - {}
```

And similar but I got error like 'File name too long' or no output at all. I guess the problem is the way I'm using `xargs` or `find` as expressions in separate commands work well.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To list all files start with number in a directory,

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -regextype "posix-egrep" -regex '.*/[0-9]+.*\.mp3' -type f
```

Problem with your approach is that the `find` returns a relative path of a file and you are just expecting a filename itself.

Answer (score 6):

On Debian, Ubuntu and derivatives, use the `rename` perl script (there is also a `rename` which is not a perl script - this won't work).

To simulate the rename operation:

```
rename 's/^\d+ //' * -n
```

Remove the `-n` (no act) to perform the operation:

```
rename 's/^\d+ //' *
```

With a little luck perl rename is installed as `/usr/bin/rename` on your distribution, too (Rumour has it that Fedora also uses perl rename).

See the [perl rename man page](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=prename&sektion=1) for more details on other features.

Comment: I did not know this. I posted a Perl script below as solution suing rename. I was able to install "rename" command with `brew` package manager into my macOS. I will give spin, I like that it has dry-run option.

Answer (score 5):

Here's something you could do using only `bash`, with a regex in a [conditional](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs):

```sh
#! /bin/bash

# get all files that start with a number
for file in [0-9]* ; do
    # only process start start with a number
    # followed by one or more space characters
    if [[ $file =~ ^[0-9]+[[:blank:]]+(.+) ]] ; then
        # display original file name
        echo "< $file"
        # grab the rest of the filename from
        # the regex capture group
        newname="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        echo "> $newname"
        # uncomment to move
        # mv "$file" "$newname"
    fi
done
```

When run on your sample file names, the output is:

```
< 01 American Idiot.mp3
> American Idiot.mp3
< 01 Articolo 31 - Domani Smetto.mp3
> Articolo 31 - Domani Smetto.mp3
< 01 Bohemian rapsody.mp3
> Bohemian rapsody.mp3
< 01 Eye of the Tiger.mp3
> Eye of the Tiger.mp3
< 04 Halo.mp3
> Halo.mp3
< 04 Indietro.mp3
> Indietro.mp3
< 04 You Can't Hurry Love.mp3
> You Can't Hurry Love.mp3
< 05 Beautiful girls.mp3
> Beautiful girls.mp3
< 16 Apologize.mp3
> Apologize.mp3
< 16 Christmas Is All Around.mp3
> Christmas Is All Around.mp3
```

Comment: While already using a regular expression, you not need to remove the unwanted characters with parameter expansion. Change the `if` condition to `[[ $file =~ ^[0-9]+[[:blank:]](.+) ]]` and you will have the new name in `newname="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"`.

Comment: Good point, and what's more, my script was a bit buggy if a file starts with numbers followed with more than one space. (Would be renamed to a filename that starts with spaces, which is really a pain...) Fixed up with your suggestion.

Comment: Also, if your file name also has a dash after the number (ie "02 - Enter Sandman.mp3"), then what worked for me was this:

`[[ $file =~ ^[0-9]+[[:blank:]]+"- "(.+) ]]`

Answer (score 2):

It's relatively easy in zsh with [zmv](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv):

```
zmv '[0-9]## #(*.mp3)' '$1'
```

Explanation: `[0-9]## #` is a pattern that matches one or more digits followed by zero or more spaces. The command above renames all files that begin with this pattern and end with `.mp3` to the part caught by the parentheses.

Comment: Note: `[0-9]##` can also be written `<->`.

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote a few lines in object Rexx that removes the numbers from the beginning of files. My files were like:

#### Data:

```
003. Atomic Rooster.mp3
087. Crowded House.mp3
```

#### Code:

```
#!/bin/rexx
'rxqueue /clear'
'ls | rxqueue'
do while queued()>0
 parse pull fn
 parse var fn .'.'rest
 rest = strip(rest)
 if pos('.',rest)=0 then iterate
 "mv '"fn"' '"rest"'"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Using PowerShell:

```
Get-ChildItem '*.extension_name' | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -Replace '1','' }
Get-ChildItem '*.extension_name' | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -Replace '2','' }
Get-ChildItem '*.extension_name' | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -Replace '3','' }
Get-ChildItem '*.extension_name' | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -Replace '4','' }
Get-ChildItem '*.extension_name' | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -Replace '5','' }
Get-ChildItem '*.extension_name' | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -Replace '6','' }
Get-ChildItem '*.extension_name' | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -Replace '7','' }
Get-ChildItem '*.extension_name' | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -Replace '8','' }
Get-ChildItem '*.extension_name' | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -Replace '9','' }
Get-ChildItem '*.extension_name' | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -Replace '0','' }


+Add:
if your extension name contains number
*add this in the beginning->
Get-ChildItem '*.extension_name' | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -Replace 'extension_name','noextension' }
***for this after this line you you must have to use "Get-ChildItem '*.noextension'|"
*add this in the ending->
Get-ChildItem '*.noextension' | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -Replace 'noextension','extension_name' }


for example "mp3"

*add this in the beginning->
Get-ChildItem '*.mp3' | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -Replace 'mp3','noextension' }

*add this in the ending->
Get-ChildItem '*.noextension' | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -Replace 'noextension','mp3' }
```

Comment: Why not delete the digits outright, instead of replacing them all with 1 before deleting that?

Answer (score 0):

From within the `Music` directory, try this:

```bash
ls -1 | grep -E '^[0-9]+.*'| while read line; do echo mv \"$line\" \"$(echo $line | sed -E 's/^[0-9]+\ //')\"; done | sh -x
```

Update:

Why the `| sh`?

This is just a habit I've gotten into when building potentially dangerous 1-liners. I like to see what the output of a 1-liner will be *before* I commit to executing it. So just remove the `| sh -x` from the end if you want to see what it'll do without it *actually* doing it. This is undeniably less efficient as it's spawning a second shell to run the command, but, for me it's a fair tradeoff for short-running 1-liners.  If I was doing this over a *huge* list of files I'd probably try to do it a bit more efficiency, after a lot more testing.

Comment: Why would you pipe a command that prints an `mv` command instead of simply executing the `mv` inside the loop?

Comment: it's a habit of mine -- probably mostly for safely reasons, as I always like to _see_ what is gonna get run as I build the 1-liner before committing to actually running it. Only when I'm comfortable with the output I add the `| sh` -- kinda like a `--dry-run` to be used when building out the 1-liner.  I get that it's probably not the most efficient, but I tend to do this a lot as a tradeoff between safety and efficiency. I've been burned too many times not doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl:

```perl
    #!/usr/bin/perl
    use warnings;
    use strict;
    
    
    foreach my $file (glob "*.mp3") {   
        my $newfile = $file;
        $newfile =~ s{^\d+\s}{}; #{} is delimiter for substitution operator
        #removes digits from the beginning of each line and single space.
        if (-e $newfile) {
            warn "Can't rename $file to $newfile: $newfile exists\n";
        } elsif (rename $file, $newfile) {
            # do nothing
        } else {
          warn "Renaming $file to $newfile failed: $!\n";
        }
    }
```